# Rating a candlestick between a range of bullish to bearish

Tags: trading, technical-analysis

Is there a method to rate a candlestick on a score of bearish to bullish maybe like on a range of 0 to 100? like a bullish marubozu would get a 90-100 whereas a bearish one would get a 0-10 and doji might get something in range of 45-55 and all other candlestick types might be judged on this scale too?

Answer (score -2):

The effectiveness of candlesticks is relative to what has been going on in price just before the particular candlestick came about.

For example, if you got a doji in a flat sideways market it would be meaningless, as a doji represents indecision and the market is already in indecision (going sideways). But a doji or series of consecutive dojis at the top of an uptrend or bottom of a downtrend, can be an indication that the price may change direction.

So you really need to have an overall view of current price action to determine how effective a particular candlestick might be.

You can't really give an individual candlestick a rating, it much depends on its relativity to the rest of the price action. But what you might be able to do is come up with your own rating system based on the psychology of the particular candlestick and the preceding price action before it, and then only take a trade if the score is above say 8 out of 10.

For example, if your doji occurs after sideways action you might give it a 0, if it occurs after a steep trend you might give it a 5, if you have several consecutive dojis after a steep trend you might add one point for each additional doji, and if you notice that in the past every time there is a doji straight after a steep trend the price reverses say 70% of the time, you might add another 2 point.

So you need to look at the whole picture to try and increase your odds, not just the candlestick by itself.